# Replace Multi Text containing

Tags: sublimetext3, str-replace, text-editor, cut

is it possible to replace and copy(cut) this:

```
fdialog(1)
{
    //some code
}
...
fdialog(5000)
{
    //some code
}
```

I need to select everthing that has fdialog and { }
Like i input
fdialog( or something like that and it selecets everything that have fdialog( and whole code inside brackets?
example:

```
fdialog(3253)
{
    print("example");
}
```

I have dozens of these and i need to change fdialog into sth else

Answer (score 0):

I have found a hacky regular expression to do this.

Press `Ctrl + H` for *Replace* menu or go to `Find -> Replace`.

In *Find* area, toggle *Regular Expressions* for regex to work and place `fdialog\([\d]+\)\n{[\s\w\d()";/]*}`. And for the *Replace* area, leave it empty and press *Replace All* . This should remove all `fdialog()` functions.

The regex matches *fdialog* followed by *()* brackets that have any number of digits inside them as argument followed by new line with *{}* square brackets that have anything inside them.